# Retrieve values from Server depends on Interval Time

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the values about health details from server database depends upon the Update Interval Time. Suppose if the user set the interval time is 10 minutes, so the values from the server should be retrieve at every 10 minutes. It's like a quartz in Spring. I tried Timer and TimerTask, but it needs a event to run. But in my case, there is no event. So, how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this on you onCreate() method

```
Thread timer = new Thread() {
    public void run () {
        for (;;) {
            // do stuff in a separate thread
            uiCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(UPDATE_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }
    }
};
timer.start();
```

Then in the callback, retrieve your data.

```
  private Handler uiCallback = new Handler () {
        public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
            //  retrieve the values about health details from server database
         }
    };
```

Dont forget to reset UPDATE_TIME everytime the user set the interval.

Comment: I am having a doubt on this, in my app i having 5 different kinds of settings for retrieve values, if i keep the separate thread for all 5 settings, how can i handle the memory leakage? Can you tell me the solution.

Comment: UPDATE_TIME is a global variable. Just change it and leave only one thread running.